# ¿Puedo indicar el tipo de una variable en Python al definirla?

Tags: python, variables, tipos

Quiero declarar varias variables en Python.

En Java hacía esto, indicando el tipo de la variable declarada:

```java
float a,b,c,d;
```

¿Se puede hacer lo mismo en Python?

Answer (score 7):

Las variables no se declaran, sino que se inicializan. El tipo de una variable es el tipo del dato que contiene. Al ser python dinámico, ese tipo puede ir cambiando en tiempo de ejecución (porque las variables son en el fondo referencias que "apuntan" a un dato que puede ser de diferente tipo en cada momento).

Así, nada te impide escribir código como este:

```
a = 1.2      # a es float en este momento
a = "Hola"   # pero es string en este otro
```

## No obstante, puedes anotar tipos

Si prevés que tu variable no va a cambiar nunca de tipo, puedes utilizar "anotaciones de tipo" (*type hintings*) para hacer el código más legible y para ayudar a los editores a chequear posibles errores (mediante análisis estático) y para proporcionarte ayuda y autocompletado inteligentes.

Con una anotación de tipo, una asignación puede verse casi como una declaración, y sería así:

```
a:float = 0
```

Las anotaciones de tipo son importantes en los parámetros de una función y en el valor retornado por la misma, para que los analizadores estáticos de código puedan verificar si estás pasando una variable del tipo correcto. Sin embargo en las variables en sí se puede omitir esa declaración porque estos analizadores pueden inferir el tipo según cómo las inicialices.

Así, si un analizador de código ve esto:

```
a = 0.0   # Cuidado! Si pongo a=0 se inferiría que es de tipo int
```

tomará nota de que `a` es de tipo `float` sin que se lo indiques de otra forma. Más adelante podrá verificar cuando invoques a una función, por ejemplo así:

```
n = math.sqrt(a)
```

que los tipos son correctos, pues la función `math.sqrt()` está anotada para indicar que su parámetro es `float` (por lo que el analizador dará por buena la invocación) y que retorna `float` (con lo que el analizador "tomará nota" de que `n` es también de tipo `float`).

Uno de estos analizadores es `mypy`. Si a `mypy` le pasamos este programa:

```
import math

a = float(input("Dame un número"))
n = math.sqrt(a)
print("La raiz es", n)
```

Nos dirá que todo está bien, pues ha podido inferir que el tipo de `a` es `float` (ya que hemos aplicado `float()` a la cadena devuelta por `input()`) y por tanto la llamada a `sqrt()` es correcta.

Pero si le pasamos en cambio este otro (en el que he omitido la conversión a `float()` del `input()`:

```
import math

a = input("Dame un número")
n = math.sqrt(a)
print("La raiz es", n)
```

produce el error:

```
ej.py:4: error: Argument 1 to "sqrt" has incompatible type "str"; expected "SupportsFloat"
```

Las anotaciones de tipo son un añadido relativamente reciente a Python, y puedes agregarlas a tu programa si quieres. No necesitas declarar el tipo de todo lo que aparezca en el programa, puedes ir incorporando esta característica poco a poco. Las variables cuyo tipo no declares y tampoco se pueda inferir serán del tipo `Any` que básicamente significa que no se realiza chequeos de tipo sobre ellas.

La anotación de tipos es un tema muy extenso y complejo. [Aqui tienes toda la documentación](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/typing.html). Para cosas básicas es fácil usarlo, pero teniendo en cuenta la naturaleza dinámica del lenguaje, anotar correctamente los tipos puede ser en algunos casos muy complicado (por ejemplo, una función cuyo parámetro pueda ser tanto `str` como `float`, pero que el tipo del valor retornado dependa del tipo del parámetro).

## Importante

Todo esto de las anotaciones de tipo es algo que el intérprete python ignora en tiempo de ejecución. Sólo son usadas por los analizadores estáticos como `mypy`. Dicho de otro modo, el segundo ejemplo que da errores bajo mypy, se puede ejecutar igualmente con python. No se chequeará en tiempo de ejecución si el tipo del parámetro es correcto o no. Ahora bien, la función romperá con una excepción si el tipo enviado no es soportado.

Las anotaciones de tipo están accesibles también por introspección. Es decir, no son puros comentarios ignorados por el intérprete. Éste almacena esa información de tipos (aunque no la use) por si tu programa en tiempo de ejecución quiere acceder a ella. Esto permite por ejemplo escribir servicios REST que puedan validar si el json recibido se ajusta a lo esperado (según las anotaciones de tipo del código), con librerías como pydantic.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías hacer algo así:

```
a, b = 0.0, 0.0
```

pero es algo que no he visto nunca hacer a nadie.

El principal cambio entre java y python es tu forma de pensar en ellos.

Java es un lenguaje de tipos estrictos, lo cual te obliga a definir todas las variables antes de usarlas, sus tipos, que devolverá un método etc...

Mientras que Python es un lenguaje de scripting y permite mas flexibilidad.
No declaras ninguna variable, ni sus tipos, los métodos pueden devolver cualquier cosa, etc...

Por ejemplo, esto en python es válido:

```
hi = "hi!"
hi = 0
```

Ambos tienen sus pros y sus cons.. pero eso es otra discusión